# How to store recursively obtained combinations in a slice in GO?

Tags: recursion, go, combinations

Combinations can be printed using the following recursive code (inspired from [Rosetta](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Go))

I thought it would be easy to store the intermediate results in an []int or the set of combination in an [][]int. But, because the function is recursive, it is not so easy than replacing the

```
fmt.Println(s)
```

by a

```
return s
```

with a minor modification of the function output for example. I also tried to feed a pointer like

```
p *[][]int
```

with the variable "s" inside the recursive function, but I failed :-/

I think it is a general problem with recursive functions so if you have some advises to solve this problem it will help me a lot !

Many thanks in advance ! ;)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    comb(5, 3)
}

func comb(n, m int) {

    s := make([]int, m)
    last := m - 1
    var rc func(int, int)
    rc = func(i, next int) {
        for j := next; j < n; j++ {
            s[i] = j
            if i == last {
                fmt.Println(s)  
            } else {
                rc(i+1, j+1)
            }
        }
        return 
    }
    rc(0, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that `s` is being reused by each `rc` call so you just need to ensure that when storing `s` into an `[][]int` you store its copy, so as to not overwrite its contents during the next iteration.

To copy a slice you can use append like this:

```
scopy := append([]int{}, s...)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lggy5JFL0Z

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    out := comb(5, 3)
    fmt.Println(out)
}

func comb(n, m int) (out [][]int) {

    s := make([]int, m)
    last := m - 1

    var rc func(int, int)
    rc = func(i, next int) {

        for j := next; j < n; j++ {
            s[i] = j
            if i == last {
                out = append(out, append([]int{}, s...))
            } else {
                rc(i+1, j+1)
            }
        }
        return
    }
    rc(0, 0)

    return out
}
```

Comment: Nice solution @mkopriva ! Thanks !